# Here i want to load data in ajax hide show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i want to show or hide data div using `ajax`

here my code working as a script but i want to load as it as in ajax.

if clicking next button it shows next div.

then you clicking previous button it shows previous div.

my script code as follows:

```
<script>
$('#next').click(function() {
$('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
    .next().show().addClass('current');
if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
    $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
}
$('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
$('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
    .prev().show().addClass('current');
if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
    $('#prev').attr('disabled', true);
}
$('#next').attr('disabled', null);
});
</script>
```

my html code as folow:

```
<h1> QUESTIONS</h1>

<style>
#div{display:none;}
</style>
<button id="prev" disabled="disabled"> PREVIOUS </button>
<button id="next"> NEXT </button>

<form action="<?php echo site_url('pages/answers');?>" method="post">

<div id="main"> 
<?php $i=1; 
$tt=$ques->num_rows();
foreach($ques->result() as $qus)
{   ?>  
<div <?php if($i==1){?>id="div1" class="first current" <?php } else {?> id="div" <?php } if($i==$tt) {?> class="last"<?php }?>>
<input type="hidden" name="q_id[]" value="<?php echo $qus->qst_id; ?>"/> 
  <?php  echo $i.') ' .$qus->qst_questions;?>
   <label>  <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $qus->qst_id;?>" value="A"/><?php echo $qus->qst_option_a; ?></label>
   <label>  <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $qus->qst_id;?>" value="B"/><?php echo $qus->qst_option_b; ?></label>
   <label>  <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $qus->qst_id;?>" value="C"/><?php echo $qus->qst_option_c; ?></label>
   <label>  <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $qus->qst_id;?>" value="D"/><?php echo $qus->qst_option_d; ?></label>

</div>

<?php $i++; }?>
</div>

</form>
```

here show/hide div using ajax.

how to do that ? please help any one to solve my problem.

here it as an example ['[plese see this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qw75j/7/)']

this is loaded in script but i want to load in ajax

Comment: You want to load content by AJAX and then show it in tab. Right?

Comment: Tushar..you saw the above example same it is i want to load in ajax

Comment: @YuvarajUraj By "load in ajax", what you mean ? You need to load content of div in ajax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Javascript:
Update your configurations for AJAX and it should work.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/okyqtj3z/)

```js
$('#next').click(function() {
  $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
    .next().show().addClass('current');
  if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
    $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
  }
  $('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
  $.ajax({
    url: "Url",
    success: function(result) {
      $('#main div:visible').html(result);

    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log($('#main div:visible').attr('id'));
      $('#main div:visible').html('dynamic html content');
    }
  });

});

$('#prev').click(function() {
  $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
    .prev().show().addClass('current');
  if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
    $('#prev').attr('disabled', true);
  }
  $('#next').attr('disabled', null);
  $.ajax({
    url: "Url",
    success: function(result) {
      $('#main div:visible').html(result);
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log($('#main div:visible').attr('id'));
      $('#main div:visible').html('dynamic html content');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="prev" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<hr />
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1" class="first current">Div 1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="last">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ i get when clicking next or previous button `dynamic html content`

Comment: @YuvarajUraj That's what I said: `Update your configurations for AJAX and it should work.` Try the same in your code.

Comment: if it is ajax loading visible means it does not shows that div content `code` in `view source` page . here it shows the div content

Comment: @YuvarajUraj What you are saying is that you have to create a new `div` element per AJAX request? You can do that in the `success` callback of `$.ajax`.

Comment: ya i got it tushar we are near answer it works for clicking next i configured that but it shows in `view source code` i dont know where it provide please you finish that and update fiddle and send it me please

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    $.ajax({url: "Url", 
            success: function(result){
         $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
                .next().show().addClass('current');
            if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
                $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
            }
            $('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
    }});

});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    $.ajax({url: "Url", success: function(result){
 $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .prev().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
        $('#prev').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#next').attr('disabled', null);
    }});

});
```

Please write your code on success part 
and you can return value from server side will get here in 'result' variable
You can use 'result' for checking

Comment: @YuvarajUraj this is not your personal debugging place - if it doesn't work indicate what the console says

Comment: `console` i cant get any errors so only i mentioned here. you have any answer means provide me.....  @#Nicholas Kyriakides#@

Comment: what you have given instead of "url".. I didnt give exact code.. it is just a sample you have to modify according to your code

Comment: i cant provide in url because i dont to do any operations here so only i cant provde anything in that. pls sreerejith give full code or fiddle example or give an instructions

Comment: the idea is if you want to call ajax that is the method to do it
$.ajax({url: "Url", success: function(result){ your code.. }});